# how can i solve the following problem in my code?

Tags: python, opencv

I want two images to be displayed to the user next to each other and the user selects one of them.
code:

```
img1=cv2.imread("F:/ML_991_Final/Dataset/1/1-1/bee.jpg",cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img2=cv2.imread("F:/ML_991_Final/Dataset/1/1-1/parrots.jpg",cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
new_img = cv2.hconcat([img1, img2])
plt.imshow(new_img)
plt.show()
image_selection=input("select a picture img1(1) or img2(2)")
if image_selection==1:
    image=img1
elif image_selection==2:
    image=img2
```

Error message

```
error:
OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-5rb_9df3\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix_operations.cpp:68: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 
    src[i].dims <= 2 && src[i].rows == src[0].rows && src[i].type() == src[0].type() in function 'cv::hconcat'
```

Comment: You need to resize both images into the same size before concatnating

Answer (score 3):

Your flags are wrong on `cv2.imread()`. You need to use something more akin to

```
im = cv2.imread('...', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

The flags you are using are for:

```
cv2.cvtColor()
```